# Por que a classe pode ser pega pelo JavaScript durante o carregamento da página e o ID não?

Tags: javascript, html

Estava fazendo uns testes com o JavaScript e acabei me deparando com um "fenômeno" interessante, porém não consegui encontrar uma boa explicação para o explicar.

Segue o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Documento</title>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Titulo</h1>
        <p class="Paragrafo" id="ponto">Paragrafo 1</p>
        <p class="Paragrafo" >Paragrafo 2</p>
        <p id="p3">Paragrafo 3</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Se você tentar capturar o paragrafo (`<p>`) que possui o `id="ponto"` usando o seguinte JavaScript:

```
let p1 = document.getElementById("ponto")
console.log(p1);
```

O resultado será `null`, já que o JavaScript está sendo carregado antes da criação do parágrafo com `id="ponto"`, tendo em vista que, nesse caso, o script está sendo carregado na `head`, e o parágrafo, no `body`.

Por outro lado, se tentarmos usar:

```
let para = document.getElementsByClassName("Paragrafo")
console.log(para)
```

O JavaScript irá retornar a `class`, mesmo sendo executado antes dela, ou seja, quando o JavaScript for executado, assim como o ID, a classe ainda não existia no DOM. Então, como o JavaScript consegue retornar a classe?

Observação: Sei que esse problema pode ser resolvido através de eventos específicos como `window.onload` ou `DOMContentLoaded`, mas isso não vem ao caso agora, já que a questão é saber o motivo de conseguirmos pegar através da classe, mas não através do ID.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A razão para isso é simples.
Diferente de um `getElementById`, que retorna um `HTMLElement` ou `null`, `getElementsByClassName` retorna um `HTMLCollection`, que é um objeto iterável, similar ao array padrão, mas com a diferença de que os HTMLCollection são atualizados pelo browser quando uma mutação ocorre no `DOM`.

Quando você utiliza getElementsByClassName antes do DOM ser carregado, você receberá uma lista vazia, mas conforme os novos elementos são carregados no DOM, essa lista é preenchida para você. Se em algum momento algum elemento for excluído ou adicionado ao DOM, essa lista será atualizada, como você pode ver no exemplo:

```js
const paragrafos = document.getElementsByClassName('paragrafo');
const paragrafo2 = document.getElementById('paragrafo2');

paragrafo2.remove();
console.log(paragrafos); 
//A referência de paragrafo2 não existe mais no HTMLCollection "paragrafos"
```

```html
<p id="paragrafo1" class="paragrafo">Paragrafo 1</p>
<p id="paragrafo2" class="paragrafo">Paragrafo 2</p>
```